# Download CPAN modules using perl

Tags: perl, mechanize, cpan

I want to download all the CPAN modules using perl script. I Googled it. I found many of them suggested WWW::Mechanize module. Can any one give me clear idea how to start this?
I tried the below code

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'marinetraffic2.aegean.gr/ais/getkml.aspx';
my $local_file_name = 'getkml.aspx';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );
```

but i couldn't get the possible output. Please help me out

Comment: http://www.cpan.org/misc/how-to-mirror.html

Answer (score 0):

Rsync CPAN. [How to mirror CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/misc/how-to-mirror.html).

If you just want the current modules, check out [CPAN::Mini](http://www.metacpan.org/modules/CPAN::Mini).